# Laravel Migration Issue: Database does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite

I've been scratching my head for maybe the last hour trying to figure out what's going on.

I deleted my database.sql file since I wanted a new one from scratch. I've done this dozens of times, but upon running php artisan `migrate:fresh` it returned the following error:

```
Database file at path [{..}/database/database.sqlite] does not exist. Ensure this is an absolute path to the database. (Connection: sqlite, SQL: PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;)

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:829
    825▕                     $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    826▕                 );
    827▕             }
    828▕ 
  ➜ 829▕             throw new QueryException(
    830▕                 $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    831▕             );
    832▕         }
    833▕     }

  1   [internal]:0
      Illuminate\Foundation\Application::Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}(Object(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider))
      +17 vendor frames 

  19  app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php:24
      Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic("table")
```

This has always created the database itself, why is it not now?

I created the database.sqlite in the original directory manually, and it came out with this error instead:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: kingdoms (Connection: sqlite, SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from "kingdoms")

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:829
    825▕                     $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    826▕                 );
    827▕             }
    828▕ 
  ➜ 829▕             throw new QueryException(
    830▕                 $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    831▕             );
    832▕         }
    833▕     }
```

I thought this might be an issue with the create_kingdoms_table.php migration, so I removed it to see, and somehow, the error is still the same even with the migration gone, even after clearing cache.

Comment: @KarlHill running that gives me SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: kingdoms (Connection: sqlite, SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from "kingdoms") again...

Comment: Run `DB::connection()->getPdo();` on Tinker. What do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that occurred here is that we were running a script when laravel booted that would fetch the kingdoms table.

But when running fresh migrations, that table would not exist when laravel ran, therefore crashing with the above error.

We fixed this by creating a handler when laravel was running to only try to fetch the table when a view was executing. In effect turning it into middleware.

Hope this helps anyone in the future with this problem

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that, in case of sqlite, it will do the migrate:fresh command only if the database exists because it has to drop tables and make new ones instead. Since you deleted the .sqlite file, it wasn't able to migrate:fresh - but

```
php artisan migrate
```

might help in that case where you deleted the file, just don't type in fresh.

In the second try, it wasn't able to select count(*) while doing the migration?

I know i wrote this as an answer, but it's too long for a comment. Will edit upon further investigation.

Answer (score -2):

php artisan config:clear,
php artisan cache:clear,
php artisan migrate

Comment: Same here: don't just dump code as answer, explain what you did and how this would solve problems.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).